# GUICE - at runtime decide on object graph

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I'm reviewing Guice.  Let's say I've got the following setup:

```
public interface IsEmailer {...}
public interface IsSpellChecker {...}
public class Emailer implements IsEmailer { 
       @Inject
       public class Emailer(final IsSpellChecker spellChecker)....
}
public class FrenchSpellChecker implements IsSpellChecker {....}
public class EnglishSpellChecker implements IsSpellChecker {....}
@BindingAnnotation public @interface English {}
@BindingAnnotation public @interface French {}
```

Then in my module I've bound the interfaces to their respective implementations, and annotated the spell checkers with the respective binding-annotation.

Now, let's say based on a runtime variable I need to construct an emailer that either uses the English or the French spell checker.

I thought of using a named providers in my module:

```
@Provides
@English
IsEmailer provideEnglishEmailer() {
    return new Emailer(new EnglishSpellChecker());
}

@Provides
@French
IsEmailer provideFrenchEmailer() {
    return new Emailer(new FrenchSpellChecker());
}
```

This works like this:

```
IsEmailer emailer = myModule.getInstance(Key.get(IsEmailer.class,
                French.class));
```

Is this the cleanest way to do something like this?  After all, I'm forced to construct the object by hand (in the providers).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First some notes:

- Generally you want to avoid using `getInstance` as much as possible, except for your "root" element (e.g. `YourApplication`). Within anything that Guice provides, your best bet is to ask for an injection of `Provider<IsEmailer>`, or perhaps `@English Provider<IsEmailer>` and `@French Provider<IsEmailer>`. Guice will not actually create the elements until you call `get` on the `Provider`, so the overhead of creating the `Provider` is very very light.
- You don't have to bind to a provider to get a provider. Guice will resolve any binding of `X`, `Provider<X>`, or `@Provides X` to any injection of `X` or `Provider<X>` automatically and transparently.
- `Provider` implementations can take injected parameters, as can `@Provides` methods.
- If you want to bind a lot of things to `@English` or `@French`, you may also investigate [private modules](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/PrivateModule.html), since this sounds like the ["robot legs"](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#How_do_I_build_two_similar_but_slightly_different_trees_of_objec) problem to me.

The easiest way is simply to go with the first bullet and inject a `Provider` of each, especially if you're only doing this once.

You can also bind it in a Module, if your runtime variable is accessible via Guice. Put this in your module along with the `@Provides` annotations above. (As noted, you may want to rewrite them to accept an `EnglishSpellChecker` and `FrenchSpellChecker` as parameters respectively, to enable the spell checkers to inject their own dependencies.)

```
@Provides IsEmailer provideEmailer(Settings settings,
    @English Provider<IsEmailer> englishEmailer,
    @French Provider<IsEmailer> frenchEmailer) {
  if (settings.isEnglish()) {
    return englishEmailer.get();
  } else {
    return frenchEmailer.get();
  }
}
```

Comment: Good description of guice guidelines from the source. I learned something new too!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [MapBinder](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Multibindings).  That would allow you to inject a `Map<Language, IsSpellChecker>`, and then retrieve the appropriate spell checker at runtime.